# How to kill CompletableFuture related threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, future, completable-future

I have method that is checking the CompletableFuture execution time. If such CompletableFuture is executing for more than 2 seconds i want to kill this task. But how can I doit if i don't have control overy thread where CompletableFuture methods are executed ?

```
       final CompletableFuture<List<List<Student>>> responseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
responseFuture.supplyAsync(this::createAllRandomGroups)
        .thenAccept(this::printGroups)
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        });
```

createAllRandomGroups()

```
private List<List<Student>> createAllRandomGroups() {
    System.out.println("XD");
    List<Student> allStudents = ClassGroupUtils.getActiveUsers();
    Controller controller = Controller.getInstance();
    List<List<Student>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    int groupSize = Integer.valueOf(controller.getGroupSizeComboBox().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    int numberOfGroupsToGenerate = allStudents.size() / groupSize;
    int studentWithoutGroup = allStudents.size() % groupSize;
    if (studentWithoutGroup != 0) groups.add(this.getListOfStudentsWithoutGroup(allStudents, groupSize));
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfGroupsToGenerate; i++) {
        boolean isGroupCreated = false;
        while (!isGroupCreated){
            Collections.shuffle(allStudents);
            List<Student> newGroup = this.createNewRandomGroupOfStudents(allStudents, groupSize);
            groups.add(newGroup);
            if (!DataManager.isNewGroupDuplicated(newGroup.toString())) {
                isGroupCreated = true;
                allStudents.removeAll(newGroup);
            }
        }
    }
    DataManager.saveGroupsToCache(groups);
    return groups;
}
```

printGroups()

```
private void printGroups(List<List<Student>> lists) {
        System.out.println(lists);

    }
```

This statement `responseFuture.cancel(true);` does not kill thread where responseFuture is doing the methods. So what is the most elegant way to terminate CompletableFuture thread ?

Comment: You're assuming that there is a thread to kill. But this just looks like a chain of asynchronous operations, where likely there is no thread waiting at all. You don't want to kill a thread, you want to cancel the asynchronous operation.

Comment: @DanielPryden So how can i kill those operations ?

Comment: It depends on what operation is taking the time. Can you show the code for `createAllRandomGroups` and `printGroups`?

Comment: @DanielPryden Sure, done.

Comment: Am I misreading something? It looks like you're not doing any asynchronous work at all in those methods. Why are you using CompletableFuture at all?

Answer (score 7):

When you create a chain of `CompletableFuture` stages like `b = a.thenApply(function)`, this handy method creates a setup of different components. Basically, these components refer to each other as `a → function → b`, so the completion of `a` will trigger the evaluation of `function` which will first pre-check whether `b` still is not completed, then evaluate your function and attempt to complete `b` with the result.

But `b` itself has no knowledge of `function` or the thread that will evaluate it. In fact, `function` is not special to `b`, *anyone* could call `complete`, `completeExceptionally` or `cancel` on it from any thread, the first one winning. Hence, the *completable* in the class name.

The only way to get hands on the threads evaluating the functions, is to be in control of them right from the start, e.g.

```
ExecutorService myWorkers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

CompletableFuture<FinalResultType> future
    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> generateInitialValue(), myWorkers)
                       .thenApplyAsync(v -> nextCalculation(v), myWorkers)
                       .thenApplyAsync(v -> lastCalculation(v), myWorkers);
future.whenComplete((x,y) -> myWorkers.shutdownNow());
```

Now, the completion of `future`, e.g. via cancellation, will ensure that no new evaluation will be triggered by this chain and further makes an attempt to interrupt ongoing evaluations, if any.

So you can implement a timeout, e.g.

```
try {
    try {
        FinalResultType result = future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("got "+result);
    }
    catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        if(future.cancel(true)) System.out.println("cancelled");
        else System.out.println("got "+future.get());
    }
}
catch(ExecutionException|InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not that the rejection of tasks due to the shutdown of the thread pool may cause some of the intermediate future to never complete, but for this chain of stages, this is irrelevant. All that matters, is, that the final stage `future` is completed, which is guaranteed, as it is its completion which triggers the shutdown.

Comment: But does cancel method called on future after timeout really kill this future or it just tries to kill it ?

Comment: For a `CompletableFuture`, cancellation is just special form of completion, so it can only have one of two possible outcomes, a) it succeeds in cancelling or b) the future got completed by other means. In either case, when `cancel` returns, the future will be completed. The solution of my answer will shutdown the executor regardless of which completion happened. Then, it is guaranteed that no new tasks can be scheduled. It will interrupt already running evaluations, which requires interruption support on their side to terminate earlier; there is no way around that.

Comment: @Holger but the OP asked : _executing for more than 2 seconds i want to kill this task_, while this code will indeed mark the future as completed, it will not kill the underlying work that will still carry on, correct?

Comment: @Eugene mind the `whenComplete((x,y) -> myWorkers.shutdownNow())` which will interrupt all ongoing tasks. That’s the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to terminate a thread is via interruption, which is a cooperative mechanism. This means the the thread must implement interruption logic, by handling the InterruptedException.

But it is a really bad practice to interrupt threads that you don't own, which I think is your case.

Comment: So how can i kill those async operations ?